# Automatically set 'xhost +local:root' in vscode for docker

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am debugging a GUI application from within vscode running in a docker container. Currently, I need to run the command  `xhost +local:root` in an integrated vscode terminal, before I can launch the container with the "Remote - Containers" extension and view the visual output.

I am wondering, if I can automate this, e.g. running the command `xhost +local:root` in the `devcontainer.json` or similar so that I do not have to run it manually before connecting?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has the same problem, the following entries in the `.devcontainer.json` file worked for me:

```
{
    "containerEnv": {
        "QT_X11_NO_MITSHM": "1",
        "DISPLAY": "${localEnv:DISPLAY}",
    },
    "image": "YOUR_DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME",
    "runArgs": [
        "--volume=/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix",
        "--privileged"
    ]
}
```